# How can I detect that iCloud Documents (remote) was sync with local app sandbox container?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I uploaded file into local iCloud sandbox container for the sync with remote iCloud. After this I want to remove file from local sandbox container with help of the method evictUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:, but I can't do it because I don't know when remote iCloud sandbox container will be sync with local container. I need your help, maybe who are knowing how detect this event? Thanks